# Possible Jquery conflict or just broken script?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion div in a Wordpress site that was previously working and now is not. I deactivated all my plugins, but that didn't seem to help. I double checked to validate my css markup and couldn't find anything broken, although maybe I'm missing something? I also didn't spot any jquery conflicts but maybe my brain is just fried at this point.

This is my script:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
 
    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
 
    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
 
   });
  });
 </script>
```

and this is the html:

```html
<div class="testimonials">
<h3 style="margin-bottom:0px;">TESTIMONIALS</h3>
</div>
<div class="accordion-wrap">
<div id="accordion">
  <span class="accordion-toggle">Blah Blah Blah 
<div class="rmore">READ MORE +</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</span>
  <div class="accordion-content">
  <div class="accordion-content-wrap">
<p>
Blah Blah Blah 
</p>
<p>Blah Blah Blah 
</p>
<p>Blah Blah Blah 
</p> 
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[This is the site I am working on where it somehow broke.](http://www.ziptimberline.com)

Comment: Is your jQuery defined before the bootstrap javascript file is defined?

Comment: It is now - and now the accordion works but it opens and then promptly shuts lol --- driving me nuts!

Comment: Ah!!!! I forgot I had tried to move my script to after the footer and left it in the footer file and forgot to take it out of there - so i had the script in there twice. Moving it to the very top worked - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving these scripts to the end of the file. You are calling jQuery functions at lines 19 ~ 62 but it is not loaded until line 110.

[image]

Comment: I tried putting them outside the footer even but that didnt seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
 
    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
 
    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');
 
   });
  });
 </script>
```

You have included this function **twice** in your code. Once in head and once at the end. Delete one of them.